# css for javascript generated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an object with an array of values that create animations at specified x,y coordinates. These animations are overlaid onto png images. I'm not sure how to define x,y values for the animations that would work in a resizable page. Currently, when I resize, the png image moves, but the animations stay in the same place.

```
<script>
// other code

// object example
var Data = {
    max: 1023,
    min: 0,
    data: [
          { x: 635, y: 165, value: parseInt(data.val1) },
          { x: 680, y: 155, value: parseInt(data.val2) },
          { x: 715, y: 160, value: parseInt(data.val3) },
          { x: 750, y: 170, value: parseInt(data.val4) },
          { x: 780, y: 190, value: parseInt(data.val5) },
          { x: 705, y: 420, value: parseInt(data.val6) },
          ]


}

</script>
```

The docs for the animation generating library don't give any examples other than straight pixel values for the coordinates. Anyone know a work around and how i can apply css to a script?

Comment: Maybe some example would be nice; anyway what if you get position of your image (eg. [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)) and adjust animation to that?

Comment: What animation library are you talking about? CSS is not applied to script, what do you mean?

Comment: @Alex I'm using heatmapjs. you specify x,y coordinates, a radius for the point and a value which is what is in the object above. I'm trying to get the circles it creates to overlap onto specific areas of an underlying image to represent pressure at specific points. so far, i've tried putting the script in a div and moving it around, but that's not working.

Comment: So I worked around it by setting fixed offsets from the left of the page in pixels. It's not ideal and doesn't look as nice, but I'll figure out how to do something fancier with document.getelementbyid() and set the values dynamically later.